# Ajax+php два результата

Tags: php, ajax

Вопрос такой:
Ajax'ом делается запрос в файл .php - в этом файле делается запрос в БД и на основе этого запроса формируется html - этот html возвращается обратно и записывается в определенный див. Все хорошо работает. Но как быть если нужно заполнить два разных divа. А данные для второго дива тоже можно получить из того же запроса в БД. Т.е. суть вопроса такова - не хочется дважды делать запрос в БД, нужно один раз сделать запрос и на основе него заполнить два разных дива разными данными из этого запроса.
Надеюсь нормально выразился...

```
        $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "Makers_details.php",  
        //data: "username="+$("#username").val(),  
        data:{            
            lat:g.lat(),
            lng: g.lng()
            },
           success: function (data) {
             $("#but3").html($(data).find('#mydiv122'));
            }
```

Нужно добавить что-то типа  $("#but4").html(data1);

Код php:

```
 $query = "SELECT *, (SQRT(POW(Lat - '".$_REQUEST['lat']."', 2) + POW(Lng -     '".$_REQUEST['lng']."', 2))" ." ) as distance FROM firm  LEFT JOIN offers ON    firm.Id = offers.Id_firm HAVING distance < 0.1 ORDER BY  distance  LIMIT 0 , 20;";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' .    mysql_error());


  // Выводим результаты в html

   echo "<div id='mydiv122'>";
  echo "<table id='mytable'>\n";

  while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo "\t<tr>\n";
  foreach ($line as $col_value) {    

    echo "\t\t<td visibility: hidden>$col_value</td>\n";  
  }
echo "
<div class='div_rigth1'>".
 $line['Category'].
 "</div>".
"<div class='div_rigth1'>".
 "Проложить маршрут".
 "</div>".

"<div class='div_odj' id='div_obj".$line['Id']."'>".   


"<a href='step.php?id=".
$line['Id'].
"' target='_blank'>".
$line['Name'].
"</a>".


"</br>Адрес:".
$line['Adres'].
"</br>Расстояние:".
round (100 * $line['distance'], 1). " км".   
"</br>".
 $line['Header'].     
"</div>"

;

echo "\t</tr>\n";

$lat=$row['lat'];
$lng=$row['lng'];
$rows[] = $line;

 }
 echo "</table>\n";
 echo "</div>";
```

Ответ с сервера:

```
        <div id='mydiv122'><table id='mytable'>
        <tr>
       <td visibility: hidden>3</td>
       <td visibility: hidden>63</td>
       <td visibility: hidden>Автостраж</td>
       <td visibility: hidden>Власова 254</td>
       <td visibility: hidden>lkdjfhg@jdfh.ru</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>087876987</td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden>45.091480</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>39.008022</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Аптека</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>876587---</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Здесь Вам установят самую крутую сигналку!
    Приезжайте!</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>10:30:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>13:15:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>18:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>18:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Краснодар</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden>0.00034174775786593607</td>

    <div class='div_rigth1'>Аптека</div><div class='div_rigth1'>Проложить   маршрут</div><div class='div_odj' id='div_obj3'><a href='step.php?id=3' target='_blank'>Автостраж</a></br>Адрес:Власова 254</br>Расстояние:0 км</br></div>  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td visibility: hidden>1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>63</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Автоландия</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Ростовское Шоссе 14/7</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>pivnev007@gmail.com</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>+79284148885</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>456</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>45.090557</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>39.007175</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Кофейня</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>7650945399</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Привет!
    Как дела?
    ЗАО "Автоландия"
    ЗАО 'Автоландия'</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>11:30:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>15:45:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>18:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>18:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Ростов-на-Дону</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>0</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Скидка1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Текст скидки 1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>0.0009192870350483506</td>

<div class='div_rigth1'>Кофейня</div><div class='div_rigth1'>Проложить маршрут</div><div class='div_odj' id='div_obj1'><a href='step.php?id=1' target='_blank'>Автоландия</a></br>Адрес:Ростовское Шоссе 14/7</br>Расстояние:0.1 км</br>Скидка1</div>   </tr>
<tr>
    <td visibility: hidden>6</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>63</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Chop-Chop</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>ул. Есенина, д. 112, кв. 165</td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden>+79284148885</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>+79284148885</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>45.094807</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>39.002655</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Кофейня</td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden>рпавыфв</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>18:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>18:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Краснодар</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden>0.006324040771501737</td>

<div class='div_rigth1'>Кофейня</div><div class='div_rigth1'>Проложить маршрут</div><div class='div_odj' id='div_obj6'><a href='step.php?id=6' target='_blank'>Chop-Chop</a></br>Адрес:ул. Есенина, д. 112, кв. 165</br>Расстояние:0.6 км</br></div>    </tr>
<tr>
    <td visibility: hidden>7</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>64</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>ООО "Евромост-защита"</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>ул. Есенина, д. 112, кв. 165</td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden>+79284148885</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>+79284148885</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>45.066620</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>38.970947</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Фаст-фуд</td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Это мой евромост!</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>18:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>18:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Краснодар</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>1</td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden>0.044327570238344625</td>

<div class='div_rigth1'>Фаст-фуд</div><div class='div_rigth1'>Проложить маршрут</div><div class='div_odj' id='div_obj7'><a href='step.php?id=7' target='_blank'>ООО "Евромост-защита"</a></br>Адрес:ул. Есенина, д. 112, кв. 165</br>Расстояние:4.4 км</br></div>   </tr>
<tr>
    <td visibility: hidden>5</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>64</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>АО "Сириус"</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>ул. Дальняя, 39/3</td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden>+79284148885</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>+79284148885</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>45.060638</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>38.964722</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Ресторан</td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Привет!</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>09:00:00</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>Краснодар</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>0</td>
    <td visibility: hidden>0</td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden></td>
    <td visibility: hidden>0.05284679360853388</td>

  <div class='div_rigth1'>Ресторан</div><div class='div_rigth1'>Проложить маршрут</div><div class='div_odj' id='div_obj5'><a href='step.php?id=5' target='_blank'>АО "Сириус"</a></br>Адрес:ул. Дальняя, 39/3</br>Расстояние:5.3 км</br></div>  </tr>
</table>



     </div><div id='mydiv111'>sdfdsf</div>
```

Comment: отправляйте обратно json с двумя фрагментами кода и расставляйте на место

Comment: Покажите код для ajax-запроса и размещения данных.

Comment: Код добавил в вопросе

Comment: @Александр Как я понял, вы echo возвращаете контент только для одного div'а?

Comment: сформируйте два блока на php и возвращайте как есть

Comment: просто вернуть массив HTML блоков. и записать каждый в свой блок.

Answer (score 1):

Возвращать допустим

```
<div id="result-1">
    Первый блок
</div>
<div id="result-2">
    Второй блок
</div>
```

И при ответе выбирать нужный

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/',
   success: function(result){
       $('#block-1').html($(result).find('#result-1')))
   }
});
```

Comment: Понял. Ща попробую.

Comment: я думаю, в этом случае можно использовать тот же id, что есть в документе и просто подменять содержимое. чтоб не менять js если поменяется структура документа

Comment: Не работает... Код обновил в вопросе((((

Comment: Можно посмотреть ответ ajax

Comment: Блин а как его достать???

Comment: Ответ ajax нашел. выложил в вопросе.

Comment: Ну не работает...

Comment: Попробуйте заменить
$("#but3").html($(data).find('#mydiv122').html());

Comment: Безрезультатно....

Comment: (((((((((((((((((

Comment: Блин, ничего не могу поделать... Есть еще варианты???